# ¿Como busco los elementos .acitve dentro de cada elemento .sema?

Tags: jquery

Creo que el error lo tengo en que la variable week deja de ser un elemento jquery.
¿Como podría volver a trasformarla para que me admitiese los metodos de los elementos jquery?

¿Como puedo buscar los elementos que tengan cierta clase dentro del resultado de los elementos que contengan cierta clase?

```js
$('body').on('click', '.dia', function(ev) {
  $(this).addClass('active');
});


$('input').on('click', function(ev) {
  let diasElegidos = [];
  let diasDeCadaSesion = $('.sema');
  diasDeCadaSesion.each(idexWeek => {
    week = diasDeCadaSesion[idexWeek];
    console.log({
      idexWeek
    });
    let dias = week.find('.active');
    dias.each(dia => {
      diasElegidos.push(dia.data('day'));
    })
    //console.log({diasElegidos});
  });
});
```

```css
.dia {
  display: inline;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="semas">
  <div class="sema">
    <div data-day="l" class="dia ">l</div>
    <div data-day="m" class="dia ">m</div>
    <div data-day="x" class="dia">x</div>
    <div data-day="j" class="dia">j</div>
    <div data-day="v" class="dia">v</div>
    <div data-day="s" class="dia">s</div>
    <div data-day="d" class="dia">d</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sema">
    <div data-day="l" class="dia">l</div>
    <div data-day="m" class="dia">m</div>
    <div data-day="x" class="dia">x</div>
    <div data-day="j" class="dia">j</div>
    <div data-day="v" class="dia">v</div>
    <div data-day="s" class="dia">s</div>
    <div data-day="d" class="dia">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Procesar">
```

La solución al problema no tiene por que ser en jquery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás enfocando mal el each.

cada iteración del each ya te devuelve un conjunto de los elementos de dentro del elemento. Por ende, puedes usar $(this).find(".active"), y usar otro each para este para saber los días escogidos. No hace falta hacer un `variable[0]` dentro de un each, a menos que sean arrays de objetos javascript.

```js
$('body').on('click', '.dia', function(ev) {
    $(this).addClass('active');
});


$('input').on('click', function(ev) {
    let diasElegidos = [];
    let diasDeCadaSesion = $('.sema');
    diasDeCadaSesion.each(function() {
        let dia = $(this).find(".active");
        dia.each(function() {
            diasElegidos.push($(this).attr("data-day"))
        })
        console.log(diasElegidos)
    });
});
```

```css
.dia {
  display: inline;
}

.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="semas">
  <div class="sema">
    <div data-day="l" class="dia ">l</div>
    <div data-day="m" class="dia ">m</div>
    <div data-day="x" class="dia">x</div>
    <div data-day="j" class="dia">j</div>
    <div data-day="v" class="dia">v</div>
    <div data-day="s" class="dia">s</div>
    <div data-day="d" class="dia">d</div>
  </div>
  <div class="sema">
    <div data-day="l" class="dia">l</div>
    <div data-day="m" class="dia">m</div>
    <div data-day="x" class="dia">x</div>
    <div data-day="j" class="dia">j</div>
    <div data-day="v" class="dia">v</div>
    <div data-day="s" class="dia">s</div>
    <div data-day="d" class="dia">d</div>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="button" value="Procesar">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```